# Is there a limit to the number of atq jobs in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, at-command

The "at" command is meant for scheduling jobs on the atq. Is there is a configure limit or hard linux limit to the number of jobs atq can handle?

Comment: Look at the source.

Answer (score 2):

The jobs that the at command creates get stored on disk. They might be in /var/spool/at or /var/spool/cron/at depending on your linux distro. If you `man atd` you'll be able to see the location in your manpage. I just created a simple ls -l command to see the overhead and the file to execute that command later took 2.5K on my disk, with all the metadata around my environment stored alongside the command itself. So you'll be limited at the least by disk size and inodes, etc. The system might run into other scaling issues depending on how many entries you're talking about.